# Add product to cart with size and color attributes Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have customized product page of sober Woocommerce theme, I added two attributes size and color, but I do not understand how to submit my selected option after pressing add to cart button.

Comment: Did you tick mark Variation in an attribute of each product?

Comment: I did but I also customized parent theme file in the child theme. Now my color and size selection is not working.